# ¿Como puedo leer una BD hecha en Sqlite en FLUTTER?

Tags: base-de-datos, flutter, sqlite, asincronismo

Hola amigos soy nuevo en Flutter, me gustaría saber como puedo leer una base de datos que ya esta hecha en SQLITE necesito solo sacar los datos de esta BD y mostrarla en una pantalla. El problema que tengo es que no se donde dejar la BD o ¿debo crearle una carpeta?¿donde debo ponerla? He visto muchos tutoriales pero solo crean la BD desde 0, lo he hecho pero no encuentro la BD creada para reemplazarla, cambiar parámetros  y solo sacar los datos.

--- editado --->>>

Este es el Archivo dbhelper.dart que utilize para migrar la base de datos ya existente, ahora lo que necesito es poder mostrar los datos de la tabla que contiene solo 2 parametros : ID y el nombre del grupo.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

class DbHelper{
  Future initDB() async{
    final dbpath=await getDatabasesPath();
    final path = join (dbpath, "programa_nutricion.db");//nombre de la base de datos a migrar

    final exist = await databaseExists(path);
    if (exist){
        print('La base de Datos existe');
    }else{
      print('Creando una copia de la base de datos desde Assets');

      try {
        await Directory(dirname(path)).create(recursive: true);

      } catch(_) {}
      ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(join("assets","programa_nutricion.db"));
      List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);

      await File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
      print('BASE DE DATOS COPIADA');
    }
    await openDatabase(path);
  }
}

class GrupoAlimentos{
  final int ID;
  final String Nombre_Grupo;
  GrupoAlimentos({this.ID,this.Nombre_Grupo});
}

final Future<Database> database = getDatabasesPath().then((String path) {
  return openDatabase(join(path, 'programa_nutricion.db'));
});

Future<List<GrupoAlimentos>> grupo_alimentos() async {
  // Obtiene una referencia de la base de datos
  final Database db = await database;

  // Consulta la tabla por todos los Dogs.
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query('grupo_alimentos');

  // Convierte List<Map<String, dynamic> en List<Dog>.
  return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
    return GrupoAlimentos(
      ID: maps[i]['id'],
      Nombre_Grupo: maps[i]['nombre'],
     );
  });
}
```

Este es el Archivo Main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pruebabd/dbhelper.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  DbHelper dbHelper=new DbHelper() ;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Center(child: Text('Prueba Base de Datos')),
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: [MaterialButton(
              child: Text('Presione'),
              onPressed:(){
              }
              ),
          MaterialButton(
              child: Text('ver base de datos'),
              onPressed: (){

              })],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

El boton Presione lo utilice para migrar pero ahora estoy buscando la manera de mostrar la lista de la tabla grupo_alimentos. que contiene ID y Nombre_Grupo

Comment: podrías tratar de poner tu pregunta en inglés para obtener mejores resultados: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53126885/flutter-sqflite-open-existing-database

Comment: Deberias colocar el codigo de lo realizo para que te orienten como llamar a la base o cambiarla, pero al crearla donde la colocas?

Comment: ahi lo acabe de subir, la base de datos se debe poner en la carpeta Assets y declararla en el archivo Pubspec.yaml , y con el codigo que tengo arriba se hace una copia de esta por temas de seguridad, pero ahora mi duda es como muestro lo de una determinada tabla.